# Java - Show a minimized JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus

If a JFrame window is minimized, is there any way to bring it back to focus?

I am trying to get it to click a certain point, then restore it.

```
            while (isRunning) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
                robot.mouseMove(clickX, clickY);
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);
                Thread.sleep(clickMs - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
            }
```

Comment: Is your jframe window parent or child?

Comment: It could be either. If it needs to be one or the other, I can change it.

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I was having a hard time explaining clearly. I have a minimized window on the task bar, which is a JFrame window. I am trying to show it. (Whatever it is called if you would click on a minimized window on the task bar, and it brings it up).

Comment: @JonMannerberg it is called `iconifying` and `deiconifying`.

Comment: Is there a icon in your task bar?

Comment: 1) Dangerous to call `Thread.sleep(n)` in a GUI.  Set up a fire-once Swing based `Timer` instead. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - why is this frame being minimized programmatically?  Is that just to make the code more easy to experiment with, or is it part of the application requirement?

Comment: Stripies, have you fixed your problem? I seem to be having very similar one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to bring it back from being `iconified`, you can just set its state to `normal`:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(...);
// Show the frame
frame.setVisible(true);

// Sleep for 5 seconds, then minimize
Thread.sleep(5000);
frame.setState(java.awt.Frame.ICONIFIED);

// Sleep for 5 seconds, then restore
Thread.sleep(5000);
frame.setState(java.awt.Frame.NORMAL);
```

Example from [here](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0055.html).

There are also [`WindowEvent`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html) that are triggered whenever the state is changed and a [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowDeiconified%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) interface that handles these triggers.In this case, you might use:

```
public class YourClass implements WindowListener {
  ...
  public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    // Do something when the window is restored
  }
}
```

If you are wanting to check another program's state change, there isn't a "pure Java" solution, but just requires getting the window's `ID`.

Comment: I tried that just for testing, and it worked. But when I implemented it into my actual program, it doesn't work.

Comment: If you post your code in the question, we can modify it to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the state to normal:

```
frame.setState(NORMAL);
```

Full example:

```
public class FrameTest extends JFrame {

    public FrameTest() {
        final JFrame miniFrame = new JFrame();
        final JButton miniButton = new JButton(
          new AbstractAction("Minimize me") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                miniFrame.setState(ICONIFIED);
            }
        }); 

        miniFrame.add(miniButton);
        miniFrame.pack();
        miniFrame.setVisible(true);

        add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Open") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                miniFrame.setState(NORMAL);
                miniFrame.toFront();
                miniButton.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        }));

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FrameTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Good suggestions, I added them and a button for minimizing.